# Record Sharing in Reports

Tags: sharing

I have a Force.com org with One Admin license and many Standard user licenses.
I've created a report on Tasks.
I have a User in a role which is under the CEO, which needs to see **all** Tasks so he can monitor the progress but for some reason he cannot see all the tasks.
What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more complex than you might realize.  The most loose sharing setting you can give to Task is "controlled by Parent", which means the user needs to see the record it is related to before the user can see the Task.

The correct approach most likely involves a role hierarchy or a permission set which gives View All to the parent objects pertinent to your Tasks that you'd like to see.  Another alternative might be a View All Data permission set.